# Appium TouchAction class deprecated, tap on coordinates

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

Currently I have a webview within a react native app where I want to tap on an image that loads in the webview. Currently I am doing this with the touchAction class, but would like to use something different since it is deprecated.

```
seleniumSteps.driverWait("25000");
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.tap(PointOption.point(1280, 1013)).perform();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TouchActions` API was originally introduced as an alternative to the `W3C Actions API`, but it was not standardized and had limited support across different browsers and platforms.

Therefore, to ensure better compatibility and standardization across different platforms, the `W3C Actions` API has been adopted as the standard API for performing user interactions in `Selenium WebDriver`.

The API is based on a sequence of actions that are defined using a builder pattern.

You can create `W3CActions` helper, declare constructor with `AppiumDriver`  driver and implement method as

```java
    public void tap(int x, int y) {
        PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
        Sequence tap = new Sequence(finger, 1);
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), x, y));
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        tap.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
        driver.perform(Arrays.asList(tap));
    }
```

In the code you actually create pointer, that emulates touch and then perform sequence of actions that represent `moveToCoordinates`, `mouseDown`, `mouseUp` actions.

[Reference 1](https://www.thegreenreport.blog/articles/the-transition-from-touch-to-w3c-actions-in-selenium/the-transition-from-touch-to-w3c-actions-in-selenium.html)

[Reference 2](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/guide-perform-appium-20-w3c-mobile-actions-swipe-%EA%9C%B1%E1%B4%80%C9%B4%E1%B4%8B%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%9B-%E1%B4%8A%E1%B4%8F%EA%9C%B1%CA%9C%C9%AA/)

Comment: Thank you! I will be looking into this. Couldn't find any really good source on the deprecation so this is great for me. Will update once test this out.